# angular detect doubleclick or tap events

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I have a workflow to use doubleclick in computer and touch in mobile.

both events will fire same function.

I'm using (tap) and (dblclick) but both events works in every device.

Is it a way to do it or should I create a directive and manually check the device to fire or prevent the execution?

Comment: How did you implement tab and dblclick events?
dbclick event fires only for pointing device

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple tap events using hammer.js and use require failure `requireFailure()` method to prevent "premature firing" of single tap :)

https://hammerjs.github.io/require-failure/

But to recognize the device - you will have to do it the way you've mentioned. But i don't see the point using different gestures for different devices... From the UX perspective - make it single tap/click everywhere if possible :)